# What is this spark straming output says?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am getting below output when running my project kafka integrated with spark.

I am unable to understand  what this below output says? I executed in eclipse.

I am unable to see data from producer anywhere.

```
17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1488886604000 ms.0 from job set of time 1488886604000 ms
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at CustomerKafkaConsumerThread.java:83
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (count at CustomerKafkaConsumerThread.java:83) with 1 output partitions
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (count at CustomerKafkaConsumerThread.java:83)
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at CustomerKafkaConsumerThread.java:75), which has no missing parents
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.2 KB, free 961.9 MB)
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1940.0 B, free 961.9 MB)
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:51356 (size: 1940.0 B, free: 961.9 MB)
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at CustomerKafkaConsumerThread.java:75)
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, partition 0,ANY, 1995 bytes)
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO KafkaRDD: Beginning offset 0 is the same as ending offset skipping iot 0
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1). 953 bytes result sent to driver
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (count at CustomerKafkaConsumerThread.java:83) finished in 0.018 s
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: count at CustomerKafkaConsumerThread.java:83, took 0.040656 s
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) in 16 ms on localhost (1/1)
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1488886604000 ms.0 from job set of time 1488886604000 ms
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.848 s for time 1488886604000 ms (execution: 0.097 s)
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer()
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO MapPartitionsRDD: Removing RDD 1 from persistence list
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO KafkaRDD: Removing RDD 0 from persistence list
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer()
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 1
    17/03/07 17:06:44 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 0
    17/03/07 17:06:46 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1488886606000 ms
```

Here is my Spark code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
import properties.PropertyCache;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class CustomerKafkaConsumerThread implements Serializable  {
    String broker;
    String jars[]={"C:\\iot-kafka-producer-1.0.0.jar"};
    private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

    public void sparkKafkaConsumer(String topics, String broker) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("INSIDE SPARK KAFKACONSUMER METHOD..........");

        this.broker = broker;
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CustomerKafkaConsumerThread")
        .set("spark.local.ip", "10.41.81.17")
        .setMaster("local[*]").setJars(jars);
   /* .setJars(new String[]{                
                "C:/Users/pusarla/workspace/spark/iot-kafka-producer/target/iot-kafka-producer-1.0.0.jar"

        });*/




        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(2000));

        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", broker);

        Set<String> topicSet = Collections.singleton(topics);


        System.out.println("Creating direct kafka stream with brokers and topics..........");
        // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, String.class, String.class,
                StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topicSet);


        JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                return tuple2._2();
            }
        });

        lines.foreachRDD(rdd -> {

            if (rdd.count() > 0) {
                List<String> strArray = rdd.collect();
                Iterator<String> topicData=strArray.iterator();
                while(topicData.hasNext()){

                    System.out.println("PRINTING PTINTING >>>>>>>>>>>>" +topicData.next());
                }


            }
        });

        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your Spark code here, without it we cannot help

Comment: HI @T.Gawęda i have added the spark code.

Comment: Publish the data to kafka topic and test it again!!!

Comment: @OmkarPuttagunta I am sending data to kafka topic.. I am unable to see the data in spark consumer..program attached.
I am only getting the output in the eclipse console which i have mentioned in the post.